# Django don't manually change the URL and go to the index.html page

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. Let's assume my project name is mysite, and I have one app called Polls.
I have 2 html in the templates file: "index.html", "df.html"
Now, when I runserver, I have to manually change the URL, add "polls" after "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" to show the index.html,

**but I want when I click the link in the terminal, it can direct me to the index.html. I don't need to manually change the URL**

Thank you and any help if really appreciated!

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
xxxx
return render (request,"index.html")
```

**polls\urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**mysite\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from polls import views
urlpatterns = [
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
path('df/', views.df_show)
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's due to the prefix you added yourself. You should omit the `polls/` if you don't want this prefix:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from polls import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),  # 🖘 no prefix
    path('df/', views.df_show),
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! You solved a problem that was bugging me for hours!!